# Is there a better LINQ Query to do this?

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a flat list of objects, each of which has a person's name, and a single Role they're in, like so:

```
        var People = new[] { 
            new PersonRole(){ Name = "Adam", Role = "R1" },
            new PersonRole(){ Name = "Adam", Role = "R2" },
            new PersonRole(){ Name = "Adam", Role = "R3" },
            new PersonRole(){ Name = "Bob", Role = "R1" },
        };
```

Now, is there a direct way to get this into a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` based on Name and Role (obviously).  I did it in two steps, like below, but I have to think there's a more direct way.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> resultLookup = 
   People.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct().ToDictionary(str => str, str => new List<string>());

People.ForEach(p => resultLookup[p.Name].Add(p.Role));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you choosing to use Dictionary<string, List<string>> because a person can have multiple roles? I would think just Dictionary<string, string> would be better. Either that or make the Role property a Role(s) array.

Comment: Yes, a person can have multiple roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dict = People.ToLookup(p=>p.Name, p=>p.Role)
  .ToDictionary(it=>it.Key, it=>it.ToList());
```

Comment: Oh my - that's nice - I just thought I forgot GroupBy.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = people.GroupBy(p => p.Name).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(p => p.Role).ToList());
```

Untested, but I think that should work...

**EDIT** Tested it now, and that does in fact work.

Comment: GroupBy - that's what I couldn't think of  - how embarrassing, but thank you

Comment: @Adam: You're welcome. Not sure why you think that's embarrassing. That's what SO is for, to ask questions you're unsure of.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var people = new[] { 
    new { Name = "Adam", Role = "R1" },
    new { Name = "Adam", Role = "R2" },
    new { Name = "Adam", Role = "R3" },
    new { Name = "Bob", Role = "R1" },
};

var r = from p in people
        group p by p.Name
        into g
        select new {
            Name = g.Key,
            Roles = g.Select(p => p.Role).ToList()
        };

var d = r.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, e => e.Roles);
```

Comment: you forgot the `ToList` call, the OP specified he wants a `List<string>` containing the roles.

Comment: +1 for not wrapping the query-style linq in parenthesis to use `.ToDictionary`. It's *so* much clearer when you just split those portions off onto another line/assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = People.GroupBy(a => a.Name).ToDictionary(a => a.First().Name, b => b.Select(c => c.Role).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
People
.GroupBy( p => p.Name )
.ToDictionary( p => p.Key, p => p.Select(pr => pr.Role).ToList() )
```